# Why clang on Mac automatically includes some missing headers?

Tags: c++, gcc, include, clang

I noticed that **clang++** includes a missing header - `<limits>` on Mac, while **g++** shows errors about it on Linux. Now I wonder why **clang** does it, and **gcc** not. And how I can force **clang** to not do it.

Here is a sample code which compiles by **clang** on Mac, but not by **gcc** on Linux:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "int max: " << numeric_limits<int>::max() << endl;
}
```

**UPD**

I looked into libraries and here is what I found.

Internally `<iostream>` includes `<istream>`, which defines `>>` operator for different types. `<istream>` wants to know limits for `short`, `int` and `streamsize` types.

**clang++** uses **libc++** standard library, which uses `std::numeric_limits` class template from `<limits>` in `<istream>` for this purpose. That's why this header is included automatically when `<iostream>` is included.

**g++** uses **libstdc++** standard library, which uses `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits` class template from `<ext/numeric_traits.h>` instead of using `<limits>` in `<istream>` (`<bits/istream.tcc>`). There is also a comment in that header which explains why they don't use `<limits>`:

> `<limits>` is big and we avoid including it

Used compilers:

```
> clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, unlike C, standard headers are allowed to `#include` other standard headers. That sometimes leads to mysterious errors like the ones you're seeing: one compiler's `<iostream>` includes `<limits>` and the other doesn't. The solution is to always include the headers needed for whatever names you use. In this case that means to `#include <limits>` in your code, even though it compiles okay as is with one compiler. There's no harm in `#include` a header that's already been pulled in, so that's okay with both compilers. It's annoying sometimes, but that's just the way things are.

Comment: I have asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214159/is-there-any-way-to-know-which-headers-are-automatically-included-in-c

Answer (score 1):

The `clang` version of the `<iostream>` header likely `#include`s the `<limits>` header, as such you get it automatically as part of `#include`ing the `<iostream>` header.

There's nothing you can do about it. That's how that compiler's library is implemented. You can simply add

```
#include <limits>
```

to this file, and it should compile on both platforms.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik, just to let you know, your answer was helpful and I voted ++ for it, not --. Thank you for the hint.